# How to protect Wordpress from security scanner

Tags: plugins, themes, security

I wondered how can we protect our wordpress site from security fail scanner (ex: wpscsan) or scanner that gives info like if our site is using wordpress, plugins and theme (ex: [What WordPress Theme Is That](http://whatwpthemeisthat.com/))?

I hope my question is clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not in the way you're thinking

### Protect our wordpress site from security fail scanner (ex: wpscsan)?

You can do this by fixing security fails, which almost universally means keep your install up to date. After all, you test for the presence of an exploit by using that exploit, so there's no way to be vulnerable but conceal it

### Scanner that gives info like if our site is using wordpress, plugins and theme

You can take measures to make this more difficult, but it will require a lot of effort, all of which is unlikely to be effective. E.g. markup indicating Yoast SEO is installed gives away that it's WordPress, as do the folder structures etc

All this will do in the end is lull you in to a false sense of security, automated attacks will attack you with every attack they have, even if you're not running WordPress. They don't check which CMS you're running beforehand, they just attack. You can see this in server logs, with combined WordPress, Drupal, and Joomla attacks, all made indiscriminately

Keep in mind that some of the most prominent, well known, and targeted websites running WordPress have "powered by WordPress" in the footer

Comment: thanks for your answer, I know this isn't a real form of security but I know some sites managed to do it an I wondered how they did that.

Comment: There is no foolproof effective way of doing it. There are things you can do yes, but they don't fulfil the idea/desire intended in any meaningful way. You could fool the most naive of users, that's about it